# How to use binomial data as independent variable in a regression framework?

Tags: regression, modeling, predictor

I have binomial data (# of trials, # of successes) that I would like to use as predictors/independent variables in a regression. Specifically, I'm interested in using "p", the probability of success, as a predictor rather than n, the # of trials. I don't think simply using successes/trials as a variable is appropriate since there are a low # of trials in many of the records in this data. Is there an easy way this can be accounted for in a regression framework? If not, my plan is to use a bayesian approach to calculate true "p" before hand and then plug that in as a independent variable in a regression.

For more context, this is actually basketball data I'm working with, and I'm looking to use a player's makes and misses as a predictor. Ultimately, his true "field goal percent" is what I'd like to use as the predictor.

Comment: Oh, I'm looking to use binomial data as one of my explanatory variables, not response

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread that. What problem are you trying to solve, and how does a small number of trials relate to it? Are you worried that a sample proportion would not be a good predictor because it may exhibit high variance as an estimator of $p$? Or something else?

Comment: yes, exactly your last sentence. I'm worried the sample proportion won't be accurate. Are there ways to account for this issue in a prediction setting, or should I first separately come up with legitimate estimates of p for each record and then plug those into a regression?

Comment: Maybe a latent variable model, with `p` as latent variable, predicted by tour binomial observations? This might be easiest to implement via Bayes. Can you give some more context?